# How to extract data from Alexa

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a graph for Alexa rank history of a website.  How do I get the rank history data from the Alexa website?

I tried scraping http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/example.com with the following script using Nokogiri:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://alexa.com/siteinfo/example.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
# I am getting current global rank of website here 
current_rank = doc.at_css("strong.metrics-data.align-vmiddle").text
```

Can anyone help me extract the data so that I can draw a graph with Highcharts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum input data that demonstrates the problem _in the question itself_. Asking us to go to a site and wade through the data wastes our time. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 helps explain the process as do the linked pages in "[ask]".

Comment: Nokogiri has a command-line version `nokogiri` that lets you open a URL and experiment with it. I'd recommend starting there. As is, your code doesn't make an attempt to do anything except find one `<strong>` tag and extract its text, which is not usually sufficient to scrape a page. Also, pre-existing Alexa gems exist; Consider trying those rather than rolling your own as you'll be ahead of the game.